# No one is gonna help you!

Tags: riddle, video-games

Here is a puzzle for you.

> I hope you got a good brain for this one ain't easy.
>   One wrong move and you are done for.
>   These dogs and other 4 legged creatures aren't gonna lick your wounds.
>   In the land of the rodents, the nightmare has just begun.
>   But the police is not gonna help you.
>   Better be fast, your archenemy is on your tail.
>   You should have known someone who wears sunglasses indoors can't be trusted.

To what gaming universe is this riddle hinting?

Comment: Please state what exactly you want us to give. A phrase? A word? Directions to the nearest military base?

Comment: @TrojanByAccident Thanks, I forgot to write the last line.

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's...

> Resident Evil

I hope you got a good brain for this one ain't easy.

One wrong move and you are done for.

> The games have their fair share of puzzles and super-powerful monsters you have to figure out how to beat. You also have to manage your ammo, and in the later installments, even your money very wisely. Because of that, the games can be quite difficult.

These dogs and other 4 legged creatures aren't gonna lick your wounds.

> *Mutated*, vicious dogs and 4-legged creatures.

In the land of the rodents, the nightmare has just begun.

> The viruses were spread by the infected rats in Raccoon City (RE2 intro).

But the police is not gonna help you.

> They tend to be completely useless and it's up to the player to save the day.

Better be fast, your archenemy is on your tail.

> "Archenemy" could be a play on the name of [Nemesis](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Nemesis-T_Type), the monster which just kept coming at the player character and could run very fast (RE3: Nemesis).

You should have known someone who wears sunglasses indoors can't be trusted.

> It's a reference to [Albert Wesker](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Albert_Wesker), one of the main villains, if not THE one.

---

Edit:

- I didn't ignore the first line, just decided to address it together with the second one.
- The *other* 4-legged creature could be...

> [William Birkin](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/William_Birkin)'s 4th form, which doesn't have a human-like stance anymore. (the pic would probably be too gross for this site to even be linked, sorry)

- Re: the police:

> It still seemed to me that they went down too easily.

Comment: +1 Good job. Think you can find what is the 4 legged creature? Also, there is a hint in the first sentence too. Also, the police is useless because you go to the police station for help and safety but they are already all dead. So no help there. 1 wrong move and you are done is about getting killed if they catch you.

Comment: @stack reader See my edit.

Comment: Actually, "good brains" is a joke about zombies eating brains. And the 4 legged creature who won't lick your wounds is the licker.

Answer (score 2):

Is it about the

> Deus Ex series?

Guess inspired by the last line which might refer to

> The nano-augmented agents who have to wear sunglasses all the time

Archenemy could be

> UNATCO agents (Gunther Hermann till he gets blown up), and possibly Walton Simons/MJ 12 in the later stages

Dogs and other four-legged creatures

> Could be the Karkians etc.